# Ajax mbox using Adobe DTM

Tags: javascript, adobe

Is there a step by step how to when it comes to using Target a/b tesing using DTM? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DTM interface only works if you have an element on the page that you can place the mbox in.  If you do not have an element you can target on the page, but want to add a new mbox for any given rule, you can use a 3rd party tag to add the mbox.  The below example uses jQuery.

```
// add a new div to the page, and for simplicity sake I'll 
// give it an ID with the same name as the mbox
$('body').append('<div id="mboxName"></div>');
mboxDefine('mboxName','mboxName');
mboxUpdate('mboxName');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it in a page load rule.  In the rule, you define the mbox name and the CSS selector for where you want the mbox to appear.  You no longer need to create a div with class mboxDefault.  It will then insert the mbox asynchronously into the element identified by the CSS selector.

Comment: any idea why i cant see the global mbox while in DTM staging?